# Trying to decipher this varnish vcl block (pertaining to grace)

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

So in my vcl_recv I have this header being set

```
set req.http.Grace = "NONE";
```

and when the backend is up, everything has the Grace: NONE header being set which is great... and then we have

```
sub vcl_hit {

    # Called when a cache lookup is successful.
      if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # A pure unadultered hit, deliver it
        return (deliver);
      }

     if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        # Backend is healthy. Limit age to 10s.
            if (obj.ttl + 10s > 0s) {
                set req.http.Grace = "normal(limited)";
                return (deliver);
                            } else {
                            # No candidate for grace. Fetch a fresh object.
                            return(fetch);
                            }
      } else {
        # backend is sick - use full grace
            if (obj.ttl + obj.grace > 0s) {
                set req.http.Grace = "full";
                            return (deliver);
                            } else {
                            # no graced object.
                            return (fetch);
        }
      }

      # fetch & deliver once we get the result
      return (fetch); # Dead code, keep as a safeguard

    }
```

So, I understand that apparently the full grace is when the backend is down and I get that if the backend isn't down we don't adjust the grace, but when exactly will that normal(limited) block kick in? It seems like when the backend is up it serves everything with Grace: NONE, and if I stop nginx it goes right to Grace: FULL. I just don't know when

```
    if (obj.ttl + 10s > 0s) {
        set req.http.Grace = "normal(limited)";
```

should kick in since I can't seem to make it, at least according to that header being set...

My vcl_backend_response has these values (for testing, but yea)

```
# A TTL of 24h
set beresp.ttl = 60s;
# Define the default grace period to serve cached content
set beresp.grace = 6h;
```

Answer (score 1):

The block in question will kick in for the first request to come in for an expired object within 10 seconds after its' expiration.

E.g., you request an object at 00:00:00, it gets fetched from the backend and gets stored with a TTL of 60 seconds. If you request the same object at 00:01:07, you should receive the (now-expired) cached object and see the "normal(limited)" header.

Assuming this VCL is running on Varnish 4.x, hitting an expired object in grace should trigger a background refresh, so any subsequest requests should receive a freshly-cached object.

In a nutshell, this rule is saying:

1. Store all objects for 6 hours and 1 minute
2. Serve objects younger than 60 seconds from cache
3. Serve objects between 60 and 70 seconds old from cache, but refresh the cached object in the background
4. Only serve objects older than 70 seconds from cache if the backend healhcheck is failing

---

UPDATE:

You pretty much got it. Objects are stored - kept in memory - for the sum of TTL and grace. That's how we arrive at the maximum storage duration of 6 hours and 1 minute - 6 hours grace and 1 minute TTL.

TTL is how long you consider an object to be "fresh" for, meaning that it can be served from cache without checking if it might have changed on the origin server. Grace, on the other hand, kicks in when an object is no longer "fresh", but you want to serve it anyway - usually, for one of two reasons:

1. Your backend is failing, and serving a "stale", expired object is better than serving an error.

For example, think of a CMS that shows articles and comments. Normally, you'd like to keep the TTL short so that new comments are displayed in a timely manner. However, if your CMS crashes, you'd rather serve the article with old comments rather than an "Oops, the server's dead" page.

2. The object expired recently, so it's not a huge deal to serve the expired object - and it's preferable to serve a slightly stale object instantly rather than waiting for the backend application to return a response.

In this case, think of an application that aggregates third party feeds - you'd rather serve a slightly state set of feed data, and then refresh the cached object in the background, rather than make the user wait until all calls to third party applications complete and the data is aggregated.

Comment: If beresp.grace means "store objects for 6 hours" why is your #4 saying "only serve objects older than 70 seconds if backend is failing"? Or is beresp.grace not used at all UNLESS & UNTIL the backend probe fails? Your #3 is confusing the hell out of me since it conflicts with your #1. I think it might be confusing me because when I see "store" I think "store until stale, then refresh" when I THINK I should be thinking "store until refreshed IN CASE we need to serve this stale due to backend issues", right?